# Play audio files without extension in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am implementing an audio player using JavaFX. Some of the mp3 files in my library are without the ".mp3" extension and when I try to play them, generates an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Unrecognized file signature!
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:409)
    ...
```

If I add the ".mp3" extension to the files, they are played correctly.

Is there a way to play files without specified extension using JavaFX?

Comment: Which version are you using?  In JavaFX 8, when I rename an .mp3 file to have no extension, it still plays fine.

Comment: You need to be managing the `MediaPlayer` on the `JavaFX Application Thread`, you seem to be using Swing to do this. I haven't had good results with this but you might be able to do all interactions with `MediaPlayer` via `Platform.runLater(...)`, this includes constructors and all methods.

Comment: What operating system are you using? @VGR, are you using OS X or Linux, they don't require extensions, but Windows does.

Comment: @ChristopherSmith Linux, 3.2.0-4-amd64.  But I just tried it in Windows 7 64-bit and the extensionless file plays there as well.

Comment: @VGR Could be the problem of not calling it on the application thread, they say bad things can happen when that is the case!

Comment: Could you please post some executable code showing the problem?

Comment: @ChristopherSmith Failure to use the application thread could be the issue.  I'm surprised it didn't immediately throw an exception for that;  a number of JavaFX classes are stricter than Swing and will refuse to proceed if invoked in the wrong thread.

Comment: @VGR Most classes do, but some don't because the price of time to check for the correct thread is too long to be desirable.

Comment: @VGR I am using JavaFX 8.

Comment: @ChristopherSmith I am using Swing managing the MediaPlayer. I just start a JFXPanel to init JavaFX, but all MediaPlayer handling is not in the JavaFX Application Thread. I'll change all my code to manage the MediaPlayer in JavaFX thread and see if it works.

Comment: @LucasSantos Keep us up-to-date if it works, if not, please post more code and possibly upload the mp3s you are trying to use.